# couchdb.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'

Tags: couchdb

After I installed couchdb， I could get the welcome information

```
$ curl localhost:5984       
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.1.2","features":["scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}
```

But I can't check the status by `systemctl`

```
$ systemctl status  couchdb.service
● couchdb.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since 一 2018-12-03 14:52:14 CST; 6min ago
 Main PID: 30946 (code=killed, signal=USR2)

12月 03 14:52:14 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Unit entered failed state.
12月 03 14:52:14 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
12月 03 14:52:14 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
12月 03 14:52:14 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: Stopped Apache CouchDB.
12月 03 14:52:14 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
12月 03 14:52:14 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache CouchDB.
12月 03 14:52:14 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Unit entered failed state.
12月 03 14:52:14 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
12月 03 14:53:53 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: Stopped Apache CouchDB.
12月 03 14:53:53 gpuhuawei systemd[1]: Stopped Apache CouchDB.
```

When I run couchdb by command line, I got

```
$ couchdb 
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{error,eacces}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,56}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
[1]    2288 user-defined signal 2  couchdb
```

My work enviroment

```
$ uname -a
Linux gpuhuawei 4.15.0-34-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 28 10:44:06 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Seems that you have some problem reading/writing couchdb folders. Are you running couchdb with the proper user permissions?

Comment: @JuanjoRodriguez, thanks for your comment. I tried `sudo systemctl start couchdb`, but the problem is the same.

Comment: The service is starting couchdb with a SO user, I suppose couchdb. The SO user couchdb should have access to the filesystem resources required by CouchDB.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but the "start-limit-hit" message is a red herring. I have seen something very similar with a Moodle installation using MySQL and it's actually saying that you (or the service start process) have tried to restart the database too many times or too soon after a failed attempt to start. Basically, this start-limit-hit message is saying "stop trying to do the same thing and expecting different results".

The actual issue will be further up in the syslog.  Unhelpfully, service status does not return enough lines of the error messages to actually see what is wrong.  Try a service start, and go and look in the actual syslog, and you will see the series of start attempts and a line just above each one hopefully will tell you the actual issue. In my case here, you can see that the problem is the mount point containing the database is missing - thanks, Azure.  For one attempt of service start, it tries to start 5 times in quick succession, failing each time because the data dir was not mounted, and on the sixth it fails with the start-limit-hit. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Always back up your data/ and etc/ directories prior to upgrading CouchDB.

```
We recommend that you overwrite your etc/default.ini file with the version provided by the new release. New defaults sometimes contain mandatory changes to enable default functionality. Always places your customization in etc/local.ini or any etc/local.d/*.ini file.
```

(I was followed this and it worked)

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.0.0/install/upgrading.html